# Wix toolset - how to use a binary file

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to include a setup.exe binary file in my msi and to run it via a custom action.  (The reason I want it as a binary is that I want it to be auto deleted after the installation process)

I saw a few examples of how to access the binary file but it just doesn't work for me and I feel like I'm missing something very basic and simple.  The log file (running msiexec with L*V) didn't help in finding the problem either.

This is the part in my wxs which is related to the binary file:

```
<Binary Id="SetupExe" SourceFile=".\Setup.exe"/>
<CustomAction Id="RunSetupBinary" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" BinaryKey="SetupExe" ExeCommand="--silent" Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RunSetupBinary" After="InstallFiles">Not Installed</Custom>
```

I don't refer to setup.exe in any other way - not in a file and not in a component.

I viewed the msi archive that was created and saw a file there, at the right size, called Binary.SetupExe

When running the msi, I get:
"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2731"

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out - I had no feature at the wxs, all the work it does is registry editing and running custom actions, no files are being deployed.
So I added a readme.txt file which needs to be deployed with a feature, and now everything works.

Comment: could you give more detail on how did you manage to deploy this?

Comment: IIRC the problem was that I had no 'feature' set in the wxs, so when installing, windows installer didn't do anything due to no features. So I added a 'dummy' feature. So I think you should: 1. use the code from my question, 2. take this wxs for example to see how to deploy just a dummy text file and set it with a feature, then once it works, try to optimize stuff: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/vendor/wix/template.wxs